# Package Installer Has stopped error in Redmi Mi A1 Android

Tags: android

I've recently downloaded an android app from google play store.It has been installed but when open the application got an error as **Package Installer Has stopped**.The error occurs only in Redmi Mi A1 while the app works perfect on other devices.

While checking bug,
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(11890238bytes) bitmap at android.view.Displaylistcanvas.throwcannotDraw(DisplaylistCanvas.java:260)`.

why this error occurs for large resolution Images in only Redmi MI A1.How may I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried clear cache at recovery and reboot?

Answer (score 1):

Check your `res/drawable` folders and move the high-resolution bitmap from `drawable` to `drawable-xxhdpi`. If you have only big picture in your `drawable`, you should create resized bitmap for every resolution because of out of memory errors on some devices

Comment: Thank you @shmakova